# I need a table for user posts (allowed to see only friend, specific persons etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, post, friend, privacy

When user post a message, he can select: allowed to see only friend, specific persons etc..

mysql table:

```
Post

post_id   post_nr    user_id    privacy option
1         1          2          allowed for friend id1
2         1          2          allowed for friend id2
or
1         1          2          allowed for friends id1,allowed for friend id2 .?
```

How i can register in mysql multiple options(privacy) for one post?
The design of table is ok?

Comment: Don't save multiple values in a single field. Far more headaches than benefits.

Comment: if i do a search in table , all rows from mysql table will be scaned if i do in your fashion?
if i have 500 million posts (we suppose) and i put LIMIT 1 is more fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by connecting a `privacy_option` table to your `post` table.

```
post

post_id post_nr user_id
1       1       2

privacy_option

post_id friend_id
1       3
1       4
```

This way several friends can be listed per post and you can get a list of friend ids with a simple `JOIN`. Make sure to mark `privacy_option.post_id` as a foreign key pointing to `post.post_id`.

Comment: so post_nr will contain the post from user.

Comment: @HoaHooksonair No. You will need another attribute with some fitting type (`TEXT` perhaps) in the `post` table to contain the actual post data. I've only supplied a solution for your "one to many" problem.

Comment: post_nr was intended for the number from post. Your solution made me to change from post_nr to post_text (i think is ok).

post_id post_text user_id
1       1       2

privacy_option

post_id friend_id
1       3
1       4

Comment: @HoaHooksonair So, you picked my solution to implement but accepted another answer? :) Interesting. Either way, glad I could help.

Comment: I accepted. Need to pick only one? I learnt and another thing. :) Thanks.

Comment: @HoaHooksonair You can only pick one answer, yes. And no problem. Happy hacking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a seperate table for the privacy option. And I'm not sure what you mean by "post_nr" .

### Table : POST

### post_id | post_nr | user_id

### Table:PRIVACY

### post_id | privacy_option

Comment: post_nr is the number from post.